# Javascript request to a cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm trying to use the Google Speech to Text API, so I'm trying to implement it in a Cloud function (Cloud Function API).
The thing is that I want to call that function from a javascript file that is running the code for a part of a website that creates voice-generated orders. So then  I have 3 issues:

· I don't know how to make the call to the URL and send the parameters the function needs at the same time. I'm guessing a POST.
The data is something like:

```
const data = {
    audio: base64AudioFormat,
    lan: language
}
```

· Then once in the Cloud function, I don't know how to modify the Google given code so it works in this situation.
The code given is this:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const fs = require('fs');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const config = {
  encoding: LINEAR16,
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  languageCode: (my 'lan' parameter from data),
};
const audio = {
  content: (my 'base64AudioFormat' parameter from data),
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log('Transcription: ', transcription);
```

· And finally I want to receive the string that the API returns in my javascript file. Which I'm guessing a GET.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code to be used in cloud functions. This cloud function will accept a request with data  `{ "audio": "base64 format data", "lan": "en-US"}`. The request parameters will be put int `req.body.audio` and `req.body.lan` and you can now use them in your code.

For testing, I used the sample data in [quickstart of speech to text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs). Cloud function uses Node.js14.

**index.js:**

```
exports.speechToText = async (req, res) => {

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: req.body.lan,
};

const audio = {
  content: req.body.audio,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file
const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
  .join('\n');
console.log('Transcription: ', transcription);

  res.status(200).send(transcription);
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Here is the request and response when I tested the code in cloud function:
[image]

See [Cloud function Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) if you want to see the different ways to trigger a function.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! How do you recommend me to do the request to the cloud function from the javascript?

Comment: @JavierdeDiosG. You can send the request using HTTP using javascript see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http